# Problema con parseo de datos en Socket C

Tags: c

Hola muy buenas tardes:

Tengo un problema con mi codigo C con el parseo de la informacion recibida que me manda un client-socket 3º party.

Se trata de un socket-server con un infinito loop para limpiar el buffer y quedarse siempre activo para recibir datos, estos datos tengo 2 opciones para parsearlo donde me encuentro con 2 problemas depende de la que use.

1º Opcion: el parseo byte a byte de arriba abajo en un fichero de text plano.

```
void parse_log(char msg[])
{
    FILE    *fp;

    fp = fopen("/report/socket.log", "a+");

    fprintf(fp, "%s\n\n", msg);
    
    fclose(fp);
    fprintf(stderr, "\n%s\n\n", msg);
}

void do_server(int fd)
{
    char buf[BUFS];
    int i, r=1;
    int read_bytes(int, char*, int);

    while ((r = read_bytes(fd, &buf[i], 1)) > 0)
        parse_log(buf);
        write(1, buf, r);
}

int read_bytes(int fd, char *buf, int bytes)
{
    int n,r;
    n = bytes;
    while (n > 0) {
        r = read(fd, buf, n);
        if(r > 0) {
            n = n - r;
            buf = buf + r;
        }
        
        else {
            if(r == 0)
                break;      /* end */
            else
                return(r);  /* error */
        }
    }
    return (bytes - n); 
}
```

Ventaja: El envio de datos que me hace el cliente-socket a mi socket-server cada 10 segundos es correcto y lo parseo en un fichero la informacion de arriba abajo.

Problema: Para consumir esta informacion con Python otro servicio lo que hago es parsear la informacion a un json y ese script python lo que hace es leer la informacion de derecha a izquierda teniendo encuenta los delimitadores que separan la informacion.
El problema es la como podria colocar esa informacion de con esta opcion 1 en el parse para que sea de dercha a izquierda no de arriba abajo.

2º Opcion: el parseo del buf text plano.

```
void parse_log(char msg[])
{
    FILE    *fp;

    fp = fopen("/report/socket.log", "w+");

    fprintf(fp, "%s\n\n", msg);
    
    fclose(fp);
    fprintf(stderr, "\n%s\n\n", msg);
}

void do_server(int fd)
{
     char buf[BUFS];
    int i, r=1;
    for (i = 0; (i < sizeof(buf)) && (r >0); i++)
        r = read_bytes(fd, &buf[i], 1);
        
        parse_log(buf);
        err_log("DATOS FROM 3º PARTY RX & PARSE DATA BUFFER TO FILE - OK SOCKET 2!!");
        write(1, buf, i);
}

int read_bytes(int fd, char *buf, int bytes)
{
    int n,r;
    n = bytes;
    while (n > 0) {
        r = read(fd, buf, n);
        if(r > 0) {
            n = n - r;
            buf = buf + r;
        }
        
        else {
            if(r == 0)
                break;      /* end */
            else
                return(r);  /* error */
        }
    }
    return (bytes - n); 
}
```

Ventaja: La informacion que recibo la parseo de derecha a izquierda correctamente en el fichero de texto para que luego el script de python haga el parseo a json correctamente.

Problema: Cuando pongo esta opcion 2, el cliente-socket no me envia los datos cada 10 segundos,me manda cada 50 segundos casi y en el cliente-socket se ve error de pipen broke del socket-server. Otro problema mas con esta opcion 2 aparte de el anterior, tambien el tamaño de buffer si pongo poco no me completa la informacion que me manda y se le pongo mucho me duplica informacion como si no me enviara el 0 byte para parar.

Entonces me encuentro en un problema que no se que hacer, tampoco soy experto en C demasiado estoy consiguiendo para no ser experto la verdad pero me he estancado con esto.

Espero que me comprendais la explicacion he intentado explicarlo lo mejor posible bajo mi conocimiento.

Gracias